# How to change focus color in listview in preferences?

Tags: java, android, xml

First please take a look at picture below:

[image]

I already changed background color in text color via @styles like that

```
 <style name="PreferenceTheme">

    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>


</style>
```

In my application i want to change focus color ( when scrolling with optical mouse ). How do i do that? I want to change that color in preferences ( like here on pic ).

Comment: in background, put a color that is an xml state list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" property in xml.

Ex:

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/mainListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:listSelector="@color/white">

</ListView>
```

Even

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
```

also works i guess

Answer (score 1):

Use `setOnItemClickListener` something like this:

```
YourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                      long arg3) {
     arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
});
```